# Where Can I find the source of this temp file in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I Want to know the sourse of this table. How it is calculated from the table. I am using sql server r2 2008 and I searched for that table, but it is not there. It is formed by manipulating some rows of different tables. Is there any way to find it. I searched the corresponding table in VB 6 also. but it is not there. Is there Any way to find the source table?

Source in local variables is :

```
"Select * From #70554TempShiz52"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables with name starting with `#` or `##` are temporary tables ([Quick Overview: Temporary Tables in SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server-2005)).

The table exists only as long as the connection in which table was created exists. It is accessible only from connection which has created it.

To find the table you should look for an appropriate statement `CREATE TABLE #70554TempShiz52` in the code.

The table is exists in tempdb database. An admin can see it there using ssms (only when the connection is still open and table was not dropped). I usually put a breakpoint to achieve desired state. The name of the table looks like `#70554TempShiz52__________...some number` (to distinguish tables from other users).

I can be useful to use a name starting with `##` for debugging because such a table is visible from other connections.